# Ansible-файл meta. Постановка ограничений в роли по операционной системе

Tags: ansible, проверка, meta

При создании одиночного playbook или playbook в tasks/main.yml, можно прописать ограничение через оператор when.
Однако, для сокращения времени работы роли, есть метод ограничения запуска по операционкам в meta.

Хотелось бы узнать примеры кода ограничения запуска по операционным системам (напр., запуск сугубо на Debian или на AstraLinux) на работу роли посредством файла в папке meta.

Спасибо.

Comment: Эээ... Ну либо ты заранее точно знаешь что вот этот хост - на Астре и пишешь плейбук с этим жёстким учётом и `setup` не выполняешь. Либо - setup дёргается при старте плейбука и тогда таски разруливаются через `when`. Если ты реально считаешь, что сэкономишь очень много времени НЕ собирая факты о хосте - я бы забил. Проблем потом будет больше. А так - `ansible_os_family` и `ansible_distribution` в помощь.